# linq to sql return only match based on ID

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using VB.Net and have two list. I want to return only the ones that have a match based on the ids from tempProduct2. My linq is incorrect, is there a way to do this with linq to sql?

```
dim newList as List(Of Product)
dim tempProduct1 as List(Of Product)
dim tempProduct2 as List(Of Product)


newList = (From p1 In tempProduct1 
           Where tempProduct2 (Of ?).Contains(p2.ID)
           Select p1).ToList()
```

Comment: from what I can see, p2 is never defined.  Should that be `Where tempProduct2 (Of ?).Contains(p1.ID)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the LINQ `Any` method to do that, as in:

```
newList = (From p1 In tempProduct1
           Where tempProduct2.Any(Function(x As Product) x.ID = p1.ID)
           Select p1).ToList()
```

Comment: @user1884032, you are welcome. If this sufficiently answered your question, you may want to mark it as the answer, so that your question can be removed from the "unanswered questions" list. Refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).